# Get the string data from database and convert it into date object in the query

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am developing an ATM software in which I want to get report by entering the start date and end date. The date is saving in my table is in the form of string `dd/MM/yyyy`. I am trying the following code and getting the exception of incorrect syntax.

```
public DataTable getReportByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
   try
   {
      DataTable table = new DataTable();

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
         SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Transaction] Where CAST(CurrDate AS Date) >=" + startDate + " AND CAST(CurrDate AS Date) <=" + endDate + ";", connectionString);

         // Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and
         // delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to
         // update the database.
         SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

         // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
         table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
         dataAdapter.Fill(table);
      }
      return table;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       return null;
   }
}
```

Please help me.

Regards

Comment: Why aren't you using a date-based type in the database?

Comment: What version of sql server are u using? Does it have a date type? You may want to try datetime instead of date.

Comment: Dear i have used varchar for string. now, it is very difficult to change. please help me.

Comment: Also, tying up sql like that is prone to sql-injection attacks. You should use parameters in your queries.

Comment: I do not not know how to use parameters in query, please update the query i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: @keni: input parameters are datetime. Sql injection (correct me if I'm wrong) can occurs only with string parameter (because it allows to pass TSQL syntax). However, I always preach for using parameters. Firstly because of potential injection, even for "safe" parameter type, to stay consistent. Secondly, because you don't have to deal with parameter conversion, because the parameter specify the type.

Comment: Even if it's hard to change now, it'll be harder to change in the future - and working round having the wrong data type everywhere will be horrible. Stop the rot now: fix your schema.

Comment: @BilalAsghar: You should follow Jon Skeet's advise. I've worked once for a customer who find it was "easier to read when using sql tools" when using string type. Several years later (when I come in the project), the DB was a big mess. Some tables were using DDMMYYYY format, some MMDDYYYY, some date time type. Then the C# code has to match the table choice in many different ways. The dev team started with 4 dev, ended with 40 devs. The initial choice has be a big source of lots of troubles and very expensive at least (cost of maintenance, buggy data, dev time).

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Transaction] Where CAST(CurrDate AS Date) >=" + startDate + " AND CAST(CurrDate AS Date) <=" + endDate + ";", connectionString);
```

To

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Transaction] Where CAST(CurrDate AS Date) >='" + startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "' AND CAST(CurrDate AS Date) <='" + endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "';", connectionString);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Transaction] Where CAST(CurrDate AS Date) >='" + startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "' AND CAST(CurrDate AS Date) <='" + endDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "';", connectionString);
```

Comment: I will suggest to use SQLParameter to avoid sql injections

Comment: The syntax is correct but now it is now giving correct results. :(

Comment: It means this query is not selecting the rows.

Comment: Also, I agree with Jon skeet about changing your database schema to DateTime and in that case my original answer will work and in future you will have less problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off, **DO NOT** turn the exception into a return null

```
catch(Exception e)
{
   return null;
}
```

It is bad practice as you suck up EVERY possible exception.
Instead you should only catch the exceptions which the sql adapter is supposed to throw, or even better: do not catch them, instead document them and catch them further outward, because if something goes wrong in this method it means your SQL connection or your code is broken.
If you leave it as is you only hide problems and make debugging much harder.

Secondly, you should use parameters in your query.

Now to the syntax error: startDate and endDate are of type DateTime, so you should convert them to a string first with `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` - this would be less of a hassle with parameters.

Comment: The syntax is correct but now it is now giving correct results. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use parameters in your query - both to avoid SQL injection attacks, as well as improve performance (through execution plan reuse). No one so far has showed it - so here it is:

```
public DataTable getReportByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    string sqlStmt =  
        "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Transaction] " + 
        "WHERE CAST(CurrDate AS DATE) >= @startDate " + 
        "AND CAST(CurrDate AS DATE) <= @endDate";

      using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, connection))
      {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate.Date;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate.Date;

         SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         adapter.Fill(table);
      }

      return table;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try, the sql works normally in a query editor, however, it appears it can only work if parameterized.
So I'm reposting the code, I noticed a moderator converted my initial response to comment.

```
public DataTable getReportByDate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string query = "select * from [transaction] where cast(currdate as date) >= @startdate and cast(currdate as date) <= @enddate";
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=(local);database=quicksilver;integrated security=true"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startdate);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", enddate);
                command.Connection = connection;

                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                //
                SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
                dataAdapter.Fill(table); 

            }
return table;
}
```

Comment: @Bilal Asghar: pretty much the same code, just with parameters as requested.